# How do I get my threads to use the same array?

Tags: java, multithreading, automation

Using Java I am trying to automate a memory game (I have no access to its code) in which it lists 7 buttons that start red and will flash green in their respective order.

As such I am using the Robot class to detect when it is green and add it to a memory module (different class) I created.
During test the scanning ability was quite slow so I decided to use threads to speed up the process.
However when using them each thread is somehow creating a different instance of the memory module, despite being the first thing initialized in my program (scope is the entire class).

Is there any way to get them to utilize the same array?

Clicker class

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Robot;

public class Clicker extends Thread
{
    ClickerMemory CM = new ClickerMemory();
    static int index = 0;
    int Xcoord;
    int threadCount;

    Clicker(int a, int b)
    {
        Xcoord = a;
        threadCount = b;
    }
    
    public void run() 
    {
        while (true) 
        {           
            try 
            {
                Robot r = new Robot();
                for (int i=0;i<7;++i)
                {
                    if (colorTrue(r, Xcoord))
                    {
                        if (CM.Memory[index] == 0)
                        {CM.Memory[index] = Xcoord;}            
                        ++index;
                        while(whenIsRed(r, Xcoord) == false) {}
                        System.out.println("done");
                        break;
                    }
                }   
                if (clockDetect(r)) 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    CM.memoryModule(this.threadCount);
                    {System.out.println("mem" + threadCount);}
                    index = 0;
                    CM.index = 0;
                }
            }
                
             
            catch (AWTException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            
        }
    }
    
    
    static int nonNegativeCount(int num2)
    {
        if (num2 -1 < 0) {return 0;}
        return num2;
    }
    
    static boolean clockDetect(Robot r)
    {
        Color a = r.getPixelColor(948, 540);
        if (a.getBlue() == 172) {return true;}
        return false;
    }
    
    static boolean whenIsRed(Robot r, int X)
    {
        Color a = r.getPixelColor(X, 315);
        if (a.getRed() == 255){return true;}
        return false;
    }
    
    static boolean colorTrue(Robot r, int X)
    {
        Color a = r.getPixelColor(X, 315);
        if (a.getGreen() == 255){return true;}
        return false;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Clicker c1 = new Clicker(800, 1, false);
        Clicker c2 = new Clicker(850, 2, false);
        Clicker c3 = new Clicker(900, 3, false);
        Clicker c4 = new Clicker(960, 4, false);
        Clicker c5 = new Clicker(1015,5, false);
        Clicker c6 = new Clicker(1070,6, false);
        Clicker c7 = new Clicker(1122,7, false);
                
        Thread T1 = new Thread(c1);
        Thread T2 = new Thread(c2);
        Thread T3 = new Thread(c3);
        Thread T4 = new Thread(c4);
        Thread T5 = new Thread(c5);
        Thread T6 = new Thread(c6);
        Thread T7 = new Thread(c7);

        T1.start();
        T2.start();
        T3.start();
        T4.start();
        T5.start();
        T6.start();
        T7.start();

    }

}
```

ClickerMemory/ Memory module class

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

public class ClickerMemory {
    int[] Memory = new int[200];
    int index = 0;
    int num = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    
    
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void memoryModule(int tCount) throws InterruptedException
    {
        if (this.Memory[0] == 0) {return;}
        try 
        {
            Robot R = new Robot();
            
            for (int i=0;i<Memory.length;++i)
            {
                //System.out.println(i);
                if (Memory[i] == 0) {break;}
                if (i == 0 && Memory[1] != 0) {i = 1;}
                Thread.sleep(500);
                R.mouseMove(this.Memory[i], 315);
                
                R.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                Thread.sleep(200);
                R.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                Thread.sleep(50);
                R.mouseMove(540, 360);

                System.out.println("Memory " + Memory[i] + "  " + i + " " + tCount);
                num = i;
            }
            
        }
        catch (AWTException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Mem Error" + Memory[1]);
        }

    }
    
    void editNum2()
    {
        if (this.num2 - 1 < 0) {this.num2 = 0;}
        this.num2 = num - 1;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: WTF...bleep are the "Threads" for in main ??? "Clicker class" IS A Thread !!! Note: The thread priority of the super thread will be conflictive with the priority of the sub class clicker so no need for them , if you want to shield Clicker class code then it would be easier to put it into the Clicker class in another name as a "nested sub class" (not use another thread as a wrapper).

Comment: Thank you that helped! but I do have a question on what this part of your comment means? 

"if you want to shield Clicker class code then it would be easier to put it into the Clicker class in another name as a "nested sub class" (not use another thread as a wrapper)."

Comment: A thread is designed to be a section of program or a program of can have its execution halted temporarily, and restarted its execution from outside its' class  , hence in the API docs for Thread class wait() and wait with a timeout argument  sleep() and run() resume() suspend() join(). All threads have a static int priority setting with "NORM_PRIORITY" as the default in its class with a method setPriority(int newPriority) if you wish to change that. If you want that group of threads running TOP PRIORITY then make the outer capsule class top priority thread and the inner thread classes normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any synchronization in there. I suggest you start here, at the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) on synchronization.

Additionally, `CM` is not static, so each `Clicker` creates its own instance.

Note that to ensure the correctness of a multithreaded algorithm, you always need to consider visibility and synchronization.